# Prove that a sequence converges using cauchy's sequence definition

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_n$ be a sequence s.t: $|a_n| \lt 2$ and $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \lt \frac{|a^2_{n+1}-a^2_{n}|}{5}$

Prove that $a_n$ converges.

Well, by intuintion i can feel that this screams "cauchy sequence", meaning that from some index N and for every m,n>N : $|a_m-a_n|\lt \epsilon$

All that being said, i don't have any clue on where or how to start this. Any hint or guidance to the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Start by letting $m,n > N$ and without loss of generality assume that $m>n$. Then, write explicitly what is $|a_m-a_n|$. How can you work in the given structure, i.e. that $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|<\frac{|a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2|}{5}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| <r |a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$ where $r=\frac 4 5$ (because $a_{n+1}^{2}-a_n^{2}=(a_{n+1}-a_{n})(a_{n+1}+a_{n})$. Can you finish the proof by showing that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy?

Comment: I can see what you mean. But how to formalize this as the general case? i mean, how to create a connection between $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \lt \frac{4}{5}|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ and $|a_m-a_n| \lt \epsilon$ (where i.e. m=n+p)?

Comment: @Zappa First prove by induction  that $|a_n-a_{n-1}| <r^{n-2} |a_2-a_1|$. Then use: $|a_n -a_m| \leq |a_n-a_{n-1}|+|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|+..+|a_{m+1}-a_{m}|$ for $n  >m$.

Comment: Using induction i got: for n=2, $|a_2-a_1| \leq (\frac{4}{5})^0|a_2-a_1|$ which is true. Now spse. true for the base case, and for n+1 i get $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \lt (\frac{4}{5})^{n-1}|a_2-a_1|$. This is where im a little lost again...